# Maximum value in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb

I have many records in Dbname in Collectionname

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("53e32f83bca58515b6eee86e"),
    "data" : [{              
        "id" : "7676722",
        "created_time" : "2014-03-16T17:06:49+0000"
    }]    
….
```

how select maximum of `created_time` in Dbname in Collectionname ?

`sql analog = select max(created_time) from Dbname.Collectionname`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `aggregate`:

```js
db.test.aggregate([
    // Unwind the data array to one element per doc
    {$unwind: '$data'},
    // Order those by created_time descending
    {$sort: {'data.created_time': -1}},
    // Take the first one
    {$limit: 1},
    // Project just the needed value
    {$project: {_id: 0, max_created_time: '$data.created_time'}}
])
```

Comment: error 
uncaught exception: aggregate failed: {
 "errmsg" : "exception: Value at end of $unwind field path '$data' must be an Array, but is a String",
 "code" : 15978,
 "ok" : 0
}

Comment: @user3916614 That means you have some docs in the collection where `data` is a string, not an array.  You'll need to clean that up first.

Comment: As-is, this query will `$unwind` all documents in the collection to find the maximum time. I would add initial `{$sort: {'data.created_time': -1}}` and `{$limit: 1}` steps in order to find the document with the largest `data.created_time` before unwinding the `data` array. If this is a common query, it would also be useful to add an index on `{'data.created_time': -1}`.